# Executing a Code gives a runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I have prepared a macro which works fine in demo sheet but gives a 1004 runtime error when it put it in the final sheet.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

'Declaring  the Variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim startdate As Long
Dim enddate As Long
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim fname As Variant

'Assigning the Variables
Set ws = Sheets("Reports")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Report Format")
Set rng = ws.Range("E7")
startdate = ws.Range("L10").Value
enddate = ws.Range("L12").Value

'Find the Worksheet against the Name selected in Drop Down List
For Each ws1 In Worksheets
If rng.Value = ws1.Name Then
Sheets(rng.Value).Activate
End If
Next

'Filter the data based on the Date Range Entered
Set ws2 = ActiveSheet
Set tbl = ws2.ListObjects(1)

Range(tbl & "[[Date]:[Cheque #]]").Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & startdate,        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & enddate
Selection.Copy
ws2.Range("A10").Select

'Paste the Data in the Report Format
ws3.Activate
ws3.Range("B7").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'Create the PDF of the Report
fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=rng.Value,     filefilter:="PDF files, *.pdf", Title:="Export to PDF")

If fname <> False Then
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fname_,     quality:=xlQualityStandard, includedocproperties:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False, openafterpublish:=True
End If

'Clear the Report format Sheet for Future Printing
With ActiveSheet
.Rows(10 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With

'Activate the Report Sheet
ws.Activate

'Unfilter all the Tables present in Workbook
Dim w As Long
For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
With Worksheets(w)
**.UsedRange.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False**
If .AutoFilterMode Then .ShowAllData
End With
Next w

End Sub
```

Error appears in line which is highlighted in commas. Kindly review and debug.

Comment: Put `ws2.` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Same error Scott. when I run this macro in demo sheet, it works fine.

Comment: Wouldn't `Sheets(rng.Value).Activate` work instead of looping through the sheets? Even `set ws2=Sheets(rng.Value)`

Comment: still the same error. don't know why is it doing this. though it works fine in the demo sheet...

Comment: "Error appears in line which is highlighted in commas." Do you mean asterisks?  `**Range(tbl & "[[Date]:[Cheque #]]").Select**`

Comment: Exactly the errors appear in line which i have written in asteriks just to highlight the line...

Comment: Try `Range(tbl & "[[Date]:[Cheque '#]]").Select` as Jeeped suggested?

Comment: And the table name it is selecting has those column headers?

Comment: thanx it is working now but the error appears in last line edited in the above code highlighted in asteriks. Now the error is unable to set the hidden property of range class.

Comment: Well, now you're changing your question.  You should select Jeeped's answer as correct and ask this new question in a different post.

Comment: Keep in mind that SO is as much about building a useful archive of examples for people to solve problems in the future as it is about solving your problems now.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to concatenate a [ListObject object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247.aspx) into a string. You need the [ListObject.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841184.aspx) property.

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject

Set ws2 = ActiveSheet
Set tbl = ws2.ListObjects(1)
Debug.Print tbl.Name
Range(tbl.Name & "[[Date]:[Cheque '#]]").Select
```

Please note that there is also a tick (aka `'` or Chr(39)) escaping the hashmark in `[Cheque '#]`.

Comment: I didn't know about that apostrophe escape requirement.